# Visual Studio Designer: Drag control on one Panel but add to another panel

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, panel

The problem I tried to describe in the title stems from me creating a custom control that inherits from Panel. It is basically just a simple panel but the class contains another panel inside of it that is sized automatically (so it can be very small or even invisible).

```
<System.ComponentModel.DefaultEvent("ScrollPossibilitiesChanged")> _
Public Class ScrollPanel
  Inherits Panel
  Private WithEvents pnlContents As Panel
Public Sub New()
    pnlContents = New Panel
    pnlContents.AutoSize = True
    pnlContents.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink
    pnlContents.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, 0)
    pnlContents.Name = "pnlContents"
    MyBase.Controls.Add(pnlContents)
    ResetScroll()
    LimitScroll = True
End Sub
[...]
End Class
```

The Main Panel should not contain any controls but pnlContents. Instead pnlContents should contain every other control inside. Codewise I achieved this by shadowing the Controls property

```
Public Shadows ReadOnly Property Controls As ControlCollection
    Get
        Return pnlContents.Controls
    End Get
End Property
```

So when I use e.g. `Scrollpanel1.Controls.Add(Button1)` in a project Button1 will correctly be added to the pnlContents inside my control. This works fine.

The problem is, I can't replicate the behaviour in the Visual Studio Designer. If I drag a control onto my Scrollpanel control its location just flips back to where the drag started. If I select my Scrollpanel and double-click a control from the toolbox I get the error message: "child" is no sub control of this parent element. (or similar, translated from German by me).

I understand that at design time, I drag the element onto the Main Panel and not on the pnlContents (because it's just too small with nothing inside). But shouldn't it be added to pnlContents.Controls nontheless since I shadowed the property?

Can I somehow tell the designer that it needs to add the control to pnlContents.Controls when I try to add a control to the Scrollpanel?

This is a WinForms application in Visual Studio 2012.

The whole Class is available here [Google Docs](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzHu1PPnuwTyT3hEVC05LWtiVWc/edit?usp=sharing)

Not very pretty example of usage [Google Docs](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzHu1PPnuwTyd1h5YXNDWkRkWnM/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, do *not* shadow the `Controls` property. It *might* be OK for a "run-time only"  control, but at design-time it could cause some unexpected problems. Consider creating a property reflecting the controls in `pnlContents`.

```
<Browsable(False)> _
Public ReadOnly Property Contents() As ControlCollection
    Get
        Return Me.pnlContents.Controls
    End Get
End Property

<EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)> _
Public Shadows ReadOnly Property Controls() As ControlCollection
    Get
        Return MyBase.Controls
    End Get
End Property
```

Secondly, you need to create a custom `ControlDesigner` like the [ParentControlDesigner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.design.parentcontroldesigner%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). If I understand you correctly you are trying to create something like a `TabControl` with a single `TabPage`. Creating this designer is doable but a bit more complex than you might think.

**Conclusion**

I suggest you drag the `System.Design.dll` into [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) and see how MS have created their `TabControlDesigner`. You should also read about [extending design-Time support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/37899azc.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: Yes the comparison with a TabPage is suitable I guess and I more likely think that it is even more complex than it really is to implement my own designer. I think I will read up on the leads you provided and then decide if it is worth the trouble for my needs.